# Background application detecting if I am using a pen (windows ink)

Tags: winapi, xp-pen

I am using an XP-Pen drawing device connected to a windows 11 PC.
I would like to be able to auto-enable an application ([ppInk](https://github.com/pubpub-zz/ppInk/releases)) whenever I am using the pen, so that I am automatically in drawing mode when the pen is detected by the screen.

Since I was unable to find an application doing this, I wonder If I could write my own.

I am not a windows programmer (but I know c#) and googling, I did find the windows pointer API but nothing, that would allow we to react to the moment, the pen is detected by the screen.

Is that possible? Is there an API allowing me to run some code when the Pen is used (i.E. close enough to the screen to be detected and used as the mouse)?

Comment: What you could do is write a simple WPF app (like a hello world one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-wpf) and just override stylus events, for example `StylusMove` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.stylusmove or `StylusInAirMove` of the MainWindow. They will be triggered when the pen hovers (in air) or is in contact.

Comment: Hi! Check this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow   Try using `RegisterTouchWindow` to register the created window as touch-capable and handle the meesage of WM_TOUCH to notify the window.WM_TOUCH has a sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/wm-touchdown#examples Please let me know if any updates.